# Adding vertical scroll bar to single column of each row of the table

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table, vertical-scrolling

I have created a html table with 5 columns.How to add a vertical scroll bar to a single column of each row of the table using html.

Comment: share your HTML and CSS.

Comment: with css, `overflow-y:scroll;`

Comment: tried that already,but for that we need to add a div tag outside <td> right?dint work out

Comment: Add TD inside div with overflow property.